# jquery serialize and encodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to URI encode a form input, that is then serialized with a bunch of a hidden inputs and sent to a PHP file.. is it possible to somehow combine encodeURIComponent into this line?:

```
var landingCreate = $(this).serialize();
```

**UPDATE:**

Doing this for example:

```
var landingCreate = $(this).serialize()+"&enc="+encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'longform\']').val());
```

and entering the url:

```
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/13/pricing-tables-showcase-examples-and-best-practices/
```

into the text box, returns the URL unchanged.. shouldnt it be converting all the dashes and slashes etc to hex codes?

**UPDATE**

Here is the full code.

```
<form id="createTokenLanding">
    <input type="text" name="longform" />
    <input type="hidden" name="domain" value="<?php echo rawurlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="useragent" value="<?php echo rawurlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?php echo rawurlencode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cookieuser" value="<?php echo rawurlencode($_COOKIE['littlr_user']); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Shorten" />
</form>

<div id="result">
123
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false });
        $('#createTokenLanding').submit(function() {
            var landingCreate = $('#createTokenLanding').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url:    'action-create.php',
                data:   landingCreate,
                success: function(responseText){
                        $('#result').html(responseText);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does the input you want your pass URI encode is entered by the user or is a hidden input?

Comment: "longform" is in the form "this"?. you're using the event submit to send the data for Ajax?

Comment: yes, there is an <input type="text" name="longform" />

Comment: It seems to work: "action-create.php?_=1290705763550&longform=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F&domain=host&useragent=ua&ip=ip&cookieuser=cu"

Comment: action-create.php sends the data straight into a database, and even using serialize, the url does not enter the database encoded.. it still contains slashes, etc..

Comment: @Gary: Yes, because PHP automatically decodes the slashes. Why do you want to put it into the database in its encoded form?

Comment: So I would have to re-encode it PHP side using rawurlencode() then? Basically just for extra security.

Comment: @Gary: For security, you should use mysql_real_escape_string before stuffing data into MySQL. http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php But **please** don't urlencode "for security".

Comment: How do you recover data in 'action-create.php'?

Comment: $longform = $_GET['longform'];

Answer (score 4):

if you use jQuery.ajax, you can see the documentation for the option "traditional." Also if you use jQuery 1.4 has the "traditional" in "jQuery.param."
what they do is use the function "encodeURIComponent" for the key and value:

```
param = encodeURIComponent (key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent (value);
```

[find traditional setting](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
[jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

**UPDATE**

you can see from this example, "serialize" works well over the fields to be sent by post or get.
Can you put the ajax code to which you send data?
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/n6qzn/1/)

Comment: What i dont understand is why .serialize() and encodeURIComponent are not escaping all the characters to begin with..

Answer (score 1):

Can you try  [urlencode function](http://phpjs.org/functions/urlencode:573) and use .replace() for hex codes.

Comment: Why don't you insert input text into form and serialize()? Anyway, What do you expect in return?

Comment: What i want is this: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/13/pricing-tables-showcase-examples-and-best-practices/ to become http%3A%2F%2Fwww.smashingmagazine.com%2F2008%2F10%2F13%2Fpricing-tables-showcase-examples-and-best-practices%2F