# Why url send via AJAX throws 403 error?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to save social media url via ajax. This is part of the form:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label form="campana_fb">Facebook</label>
        <input type="text" id="campana_fb" name="campana_fb" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label form="campana_tw">Twitter</label>
        <input type="text" id="campana_tw" name="campana_tw" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label form="campana_in">Instagram</label>
        <input type="text" id="campana_in" name="campana_in" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

The ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST", 
    url : $("#formulario").attr('action'),
    dataType : 'json', 
    data : {
        campana_descripcion: campana_descripcion, 
        campana_nombre: $("#campana_nombre").val(),
        camapana_meta: $("#camapana_meta").val(),
        campana_id: $("#campana_id").val(),
        cuenta_1: $("#cuenta_1").val(),
        banco_1: $("#banco_1").val(),
        cuenta_2: $("#cuenta_2").val(),
        banco_2: $("#banco_2").val(),
        campana_fb: encodeURI($("#campana_fb").val()),
        campana_tw: encodeURI($("#campana_tw").val()),
        campana_in: encodeURI($("#campana_in").val()),
    }, 
    success : function(respuesta){
        $.unblockUI();
        if(respuesta.estado){
            alerta(respuesta.mensaje, 'success');
            CKEDITOR.instances.campana_descripcion.setData("");
        }
        else{
            alerta(respuesta.mensaje, 'error');
        }
    }, 
    error: function(error){
        $.unblockUI();
        alerta(error.responseText, 'error');
    }
});
```

As you can see I tried with `encodeURI` but still doesn't work, I still get `Request Method:POST Status Code:403 Forbidden` only when I enter Urls, otherwise the data is saved successfuly.

I added header at the constructor

```
class Campana extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        ...
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
    }
```

The Forbidden status only happens when I enter urls at inputs and on production, at local I don't have any issues.

Comment: Try with `url : $("#formulario").prop('action'),`

Comment: @JohnR the problem is not with the form url (action), it is with the input value I want to send `<input type="text" id="campana_tw" name="campana_tw" class="form-control">` this input contain url like `https://twitter.com/CinematecaNic`

Comment: dont need encode url  campana_fb: encodeURI(), just send as normal text value?

Comment: @Gopal I already try it before but I sitll get `Status Code:403 Forbidden`

Comment: @laviku Can you read the comments of this OP? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277758/jquery-serialize-and-encodeuricomponent

Answer (score 0):

Hi Laviku replace encodeURI with encodeURIComponent
Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Sorry i can't comment not enough points :)

Although this doesn't answer the question why encodeURI doesn't work, have you tried serializing the form like this:

```
var form = $("#formulario");

$.ajax({
type : "POST", 
url : form.attr('action'),
dataType : 'json', 
data : form.serialize() + "&campana_descripcion=" + campana_descripcion, 
success : function(respuesta){
    $.unblockUI();
    if(respuesta.estado){
        alerta(respuesta.mensaje, 'success');
        CKEDITOR.instances.campana_descripcion.setData("");
    }
    else{
        alerta(respuesta.mensaje, 'error');
    }
}, 
error: function(error){
    $.unblockUI();
    alerta(error.responseText, 'error');
}
});
```

Comment: Do you have FireBug or any other debuggin tools installed can you comment or add the Post content? Also are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I don't get any error, this only happens on production.

Comment: Or can you not just use serialize? Oh right, What webserver are you using NGINX?

Comment: I tried with serialize, no chance.. I'm using Apache

Comment: Running out of ideas, do you have access to the Apache logs?

Answer (score 0):

In ajax you mention datatype is json but here just pass the value, So remove it

```
$.ajax({
type : "POST", 
url : $("#formulario").attr('action'),

data : {
    campana_descripcion: campana_descripcion, 
    campana_nombre: $("#campana_nombre").val(),
    camapana_meta: $("#camapana_meta").val(),
    campana_id: $("#campana_id").val(),
    cuenta_1: $("#cuenta_1").val(),
    banco_1: $("#banco_1").val(),
    cuenta_2: $("#cuenta_2").val(),
    banco_2: $("#banco_2").val(),
    campana_fb: encodeURI($("#campana_fb").val()),
    campana_tw: encodeURI($("#campana_tw").val()),
    campana_in: encodeURI($("#campana_in").val()),
}, 
success : function(respuesta){
    $.unblockUI();
    if(respuesta.estado){
        alerta(respuesta.mensaje, 'success');
        CKEDITOR.instances.campana_descripcion.setData("");
    }
    else{
        alerta(respuesta.mensaje, 'error');
    }
}, 
error: function(error){
    $.unblockUI();
    alerta(error.responseText, 'error');
}
});
```